# How to conditionally set tox variables depending on the platform

Tags: pytest, tox, coverage.py

Some of my tests only run under Linux, but others run everywhere. I'd like to set the minimum coverage variable to a higher value when running on Linux, than when running on my desktop Mac.

How can I do that?

Here's a bit of my tox.ini:

```
[tox]
MINCOVERAGE = 35
envlist = py37

[testenv]
commands =
    pytest -v -v -x --fulltrace --tb=long --showlocals \
    --cov={envsitepackagesdir}/secretsapi --cov-report=html --no-cov-on-fail \
    --cov-fail-under={[tox]MINCOVERAGE} mypackage/tests
```

I'd like to set MINCOVERAGE to 70 when on Linux, and 35 when on other platforms.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define OS-specific environments and set an environment variable with different value for each OS:

```
[tox]
envlist = py37-{linux,mac,win}

[testenv]
platform =
    linux: linux
    mac: darwin
    win: win32
deps =
    pytest
    pytest-cov
setenv =
    MINCOVERAGE = 35  # default for mac, win
    linux: MINCOVERAGE = 70  # special for linux
commands =
    pytest ... --cov-fail-under={env:MINCOVERAGE}
```

Reference in `tox` docs, as pointed out by @sinoroc in the comments: [Platform specification](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/platform.html).

Comment: The doc: https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/platform.html

Comment: I didn't need the result in the environment - but it certainly doesn't hurt either...  Thanks!